# Is it the recommend way to wrap providers/modules in factorys?

Tags: angularjs

For example I use

https://github.com/alexcrack/angular-ui-notification

It is recommend / cleaner to wrap such modules in seperate factorys?

Thanks!

Here is a example with toastr where its wrapped in a factory:

```
app.factory('notificationFactory', function () {
    return {
        success: function (text) {
            toastr.success(text,"Success");
        },
        error: function (text) {
            toastr.error(text, "Error");
        }
    };
});
```

Are there some benefits instead of using it directly in the controller:

```
toastr.success("Everything fine!","Success");
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense to me. What are you talking about? Give a concrete example. A module is just a collection of angular components (controllers, directives, services, filters). I don't see how you could wrap that into a factory.

Comment: done ;-) I updated my question.

Comment: If you have many calls to your wrapping service, and want to always use the same "Success" and "Error" arguments, then yes, it's useful: it avoids code duplication. If you wrap for the sake of wrapping, then no, it's not useful.